# Form Input from Link

Tags: php, jquery, input, hyperlink

So I have:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="placeholder" value="" />
```

What is the best way to go about defining the value based on the link?

ie.

```
http://mysite.com/valueplacer?=thisisthevalue
```

Does this:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="placeholder" value="thisisthevalue" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="placeholder" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>" />
```

This is assuming that you are going to place a `q` there in the query string, as the key for the variable. This means the query string will look like

```
http://mysite.com/valueplacer?q=thisisthevalue
```

The `htmlspecialchars()` is for security.

If you actually do want your URL to look like that, you will need to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

I would **not** recommend doing it like that. Just use GET params as how they were intended.

Comment: Sorry, use the GET params as they were intended?

Comment: @John I mean, just do `?q=value` not `?=value` (unless that was a typo).

Comment: ah gotcha, yea I overlooked that. Thanks..going to try it out.

Comment: hmmm. Doesn't seem to be working. I have index.php in a directory(foo) on mysite.com. So, http://mysite.com/foo/?q=thisisthevalue.
And then I have <input type="text" onfocus="" id="keyword" placeholder="foo" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);?>" /> in index.php